# .Net core 6 - About Async Task run in constructor, the VSCode Debugger is not work

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, async-await, scheduled-tasks

I have a Task that needs to continuously poll devices for information, so I created the Task in the constructor.

```
public DeviceManager()
{
    Task.Run(Polling);
}

private Func<Task> Polling()
{
    return async () =>
        {
            while (true)
            {
                await GetInfo();
                await Task.Delay(60 * 1000);
            }
        }
}
```

I usually run dotnet watch --no-hot-reload to test my program, but now I want to debug it.

However, when the debugger is running, it hangs in this while loop.

Please let me know why I cannot debug in this situation.

Thanks.

Comment: `I created the Task in the constructor.` that's the bug. Since you never stored the task anywhere, it got garbage-collected when the constructor exited before it even had a chance to start. This isn't a debugging issue

Comment: Why did you use the `asp.net-core` tag? Where is `DeviceManager` created? That matters *a lot*. Unless you created a background service, or `DeviceManager` is a singleton, the class itself will be garbage-collected soon. Web servers are built to create and clean up resources after every request.

Comment: The article [The Dangers of Implementing Recurring Background Tasks In ASP.NET](https://haacked.com/archive/2011/10/16/the-dangers-of-implementing-recurring-background-tasks-in-asp-net.aspx/) explains why you can't just start a never ending task.  [How to run Background Tasks in ASP.NET](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/how-to-run-background-tasks-in-aspnet) explains how to do it correctly in ASP.NET (not Core). In short, you can do it through some low-level calls or you can use a scheduling library

Comment: In ASP.NET Core, [Background tasks with hosted services in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio) shows how to run tasks in the background and includes two examples, a timer service and a queue processor. Once again though, for advanced scenarios it's better to use a library like Coravel, Hangfire, Quartz.NET and more

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos those four comments would make a good answer. Why didn't you post it as such? (just curious - some SO rule i dont know?)

Comment: It's only a guess that the OP want's to create a timed task in ASP.NET Core, and there are dozens of duplicates already. The correct action here would be to close the question as duplicate

Answer (score 1):

The task is never stored anywhere so it's probably garbage-collected before it ever has a chance to get scheduled for execution. In fact, unless `DeviceManager` is a Singleton, the class itself may get garbage-collected as soon as the request that spawned it completes. A Task isn't a thread, it represents some work that needs to complete in the future. If the task itself gets orphaned before it gets scheduled, the work is lost.

Creating background services in ASP.NET Core is done by implementing the IHostedService interface. This is described in [Background tasks with hosted services in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio). That article shows both a [poll service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio#timed-background-tasks) and a queued job service example.

The timed background service is pretty simple and uses a timer to call its `DoWork` method periodically:

```
public class TimedHostedService : IHostedService, IDisposable
{
    private int executionCount = 0;
    private readonly ILogger<TimedHostedService> _logger;
    private Timer? _timer = null;

    public TimedHostedService(ILogger<TimedHostedService> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    private void DoWork(object? state)
    {
        var count = Interlocked.Increment(ref executionCount);

        _logger.LogInformation(
            "Timed Hosted Service is working. Count: {Count}", count);
    }

    public Task StartAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        _logger.LogInformation("Timed Hosted Service running.");

        _timer = new Timer(DoWork, null, TimeSpan.Zero,
            TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    public Task StopAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        _logger.LogInformation("Timed Hosted Service is stopping.");

        _timer?.Change(Timeout.Infinite, 0);

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _timer?.Dispose();
    }
}
```

The `StartAsync` and `StopAsync` are called by the ASP.NET Core host to start and stop the service. In this case all they have to do is start and stop the timer.